# Custom Product Url-Resolver in Hybris

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to write URL Resolver in Hybris but I am facing with couple of errors;

The method `getBaseProduct(ProductModel)` is undefined for the type `TrialProductModelUrlResolver`

The method `getCategoryPath(CategoryModel)` in the type `DefaultCategoryModelUrlResolver` is not applicable for the arguments (ProductModel)

The method getProductForCode(String) in the type ProductService is not applicable for the arguments (ProductModel)

```
public class TrailerProductModelUrlResolver extends DefaultCategoryModelUrlResolver {

private TrailerURLNormalizationStrategy trailerURLNormalizationStrategy;

@Autowired
private ProductService productService;

@Override
protected String resolveInternal(final ProductModel source) {
    final ProductModel baseProduct = getBaseProduct(source);
    final BaseSiteModel currentBaseSite = getBaseSiteService().getCurrentBaseSite();
    String url = getPattern();

    if ((currentBaseSite != null) && (url.contains("{baseSite-uid}"))) {
        url = url.replace("{baseSite-uid}", currentBaseSite.getUid());
    }

    if (url.contains("{category-path}")) {
        url = url.replace("{category-path}", trailerURLNormalizationStrategy.normalizeString(buildPathString(getCategoryPath(source))));
    }

    if (url.contains("{product-name}")) {
        String productName = source.getName(TrailerCoreConstants.LOCALE_TR);

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(productName)) {
            productName = baseProduct.getName(TrailerCoreConstants.LOCALE_TR);
        }

        CategoryModel categoryModel = productService.getProductForCode(baseProduct);
        if (categoryModel != null) {
            if (categoryModel.getName() != null) {
                if (!categoryModel.getName(TrailerCoreConstants.LOCALE_TR).isEmpty()) {
                    productName = categoryModel.getName(TrailerCoreConstants.LOCALE_TR) + " " + productName;
                }
            }
        }
        url = url.replace("{product-name}", trailerURLNormalizationStrategy.normalizeString(productName));
    }

    if (url.contains("{product-code}")) {
        url = url.replace("{product-code}", trailerURLNormalizationStrategy.normalizeString(source.getCode()));
    }

    return url;
}

@Override
protected String buildPathString(final List<CategoryModel> path) {
    if ((path == null) || (path.isEmpty())) {
        return "c";
    }

    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); ++i) {
        if (i != 0) {
            result.append('/');
        }
        result.append(path.get(i).getName());
    }

    return result.toString();
}

public TrailerURLNormalizationStrategy getTrailerURLNormalizationStrategy() {
    return trailerURLNormalizationStrategy;
}

public void setTrailerURLNormalizationStrategy(TrailerURLNormalizationStrategy trailerURLNormalizationStrategy) {
    this.trailerURLNormalizationStrategy = trailerURLNormalizationStrategy;
}
}
```

any help

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `DefaultCategoryModelUrlResolver` to `DefaultProductModelUrlResolver`

For the Product UrlResolver, extend DefaultProductModelUrlResolver

```
public class TrailerProductModelUrlResolver extends DefaultProductModelUrlResolver
{

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TrailerProductModelUrlResolver.class);
    @Override
    protected String resolveInternal(final ProductModel source)
    {
        final ProductModel baseProduct = getBaseProduct(source);
        ...
    }
}
```

---

For Category UrlResolver, extend DefaultCategoryModelUrlResolver

```
public class TrailerCategoryModelUrlResolver extends DefaultCategoryModelUrlResolver
{
    @Override
    protected String resolveInternal(CategoryModel source)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir I just got 1 error left;       CategoryModel categoryModel = productService.getProductForCode(baseProduct);
   [yjavac]                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The method getProductForCode(String) in the type ProductService is not applicable for the arguments (ProductModel)

Comment: `productService.getProductForCode` accept the product code and return ProductModel, not the CategoryModel. If you check your code `CategoryModel categoryModel = productService.getProductForCode(baseProduct);` is not correct. Here you are passing `ProductModel` and expecting `CatergoryModel`

Comment: ProductModel productModel = productService.getProductForCode(baseProduct); change the code like this still ı got error

Comment: Can you edit your class in question with what you have now

Comment: ProductModel productModel = productService.getProductForCode(baseProduct);
            if (productModel != null) {
                if (productModel.getName() != null) {
                    if (!productModel.getName(TrailerCoreConstants.LOCALE_TR).isEmpty()) {
                        productName = productModel.getName(TrailerCoreConstants.LOCALE_TR) + " " + productName;
                    }
                }
            }
            url = url.replace("{product-name}", trailerURLNormalizationStrategy.normalizeString(productName));
        }

Comment: Replace `if (url.contains("{product-name}")) {}` block with  `if (url.contains("{product-name}"))
  {
   url = url.replace("{product-name}", urlSafe(baseProduct.getName()));
  }`

Comment: I replaced but still did not work    if (url.contains("{product-name}")) {
            String productName = source.getName(TrailerCoreConstants.LOCALE_TR);

           /* if (StringUtils.isEmpty(productName)) {
                productName = baseProduct.getName(TrailerCoreConstants.LOCALE_TR);
            }*/

            if (url.contains("{product-name}")) {
                { url = url.replace("{product-name}", urlSafe(baseProduct.getName())); }
            }

Comment: removed all code you posted in above comment, and only keep which I have given